# Загрузки index страниц.

Tags: php, javascript

Привет народ. Две разные index.php необходимо загружать попеременно при обновлении странички. Как реализовать? Заранее спасибо!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сервере в сессионных данных запоминайте какую страничку отдавали в последний раз, отдавайте другую, и запоминайте её.

```
$_SESSION['lastIndexPage']
```

Comment: Руки не настолько прямы, можно подробности.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VrjuajFF как то так в общих чертах